# Powershell command to command/script to check how many active users (local & domain) are currently logged in

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, get-wmiobject

I am looking for command/script to check how many users (local & domain) are currently logged in and have been active within the last 30 minutes so that I can decide to go for machine reboot or not.
Hopefully without Get-ADUser.

I came across two scripts but on executing they are returning only my information where on server I can see more than 5 user are logged in.

Script1

```
function Get-LoggedOnUser {
#Requires -Version 2.0            
[CmdletBinding()]            
 Param             
   (                       
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
               Position=0,                          
               ValueFromPipeline=$true,            
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]            
    [String[]]$ComputerName
   )#End Param

Begin            
{            
 Write-Host "`n Checking Users . . . "
 $i = 0            
}#Begin          
Process            
{
    $ComputerName | Foreach-object {
    $Computer = $_
    try
        {
            $processinfo = @(Get-WmiObject -class win32_process -ComputerName $Computer -EA "Stop")
                if ($processinfo)
                {    
                    $processinfo | Foreach-Object {$_.GetOwner().User} | 
                    Where-Object {$_ -ne "NETWORK SERVICE" -and $_ -ne "LOCAL SERVICE" -and $_ -ne "SYSTEM"} |
                    Sort-Object -Unique |
                    ForEach-Object { New-Object psobject -Property @{Computer=$Computer;LoggedOn=$_} } | 
                    Select-Object Computer,LoggedOn
                }#If
        }
    catch
        {
            "Cannot find any processes running on $computer" | Out-Host
        }
     }#Forech-object(ComputerName)       

}#Process
End
{

}#End

}#Get-LoggedOnUser
```

Script2

```
$regexa = '.+Domain="(.+)",Name="(.+)"$';
$regexd = '.+LogonId="(\d+)"$';
$logontype = @{"0"="Local System";
"2"="Interactive";
"3"="Network";
"4"="Batch";
"5"="Service";
"7"="Unlock";
"8"="NetworkCleartext";
"9"="NewCredentials";
"10"="RemoteInteractive";
"11"="CachedInteractive";
};
$logon_sessions = @(gwmi win32_logonsession);
$logon_users = @(gwmi win32_loggedonuser);
$session_user = @{};
$logon_users |% {$_.antecedent -match $regexa > $nul;
$username = $matches[1] + "\" + $matches[2];
$_.dependent -match $regexd > $nul;
$session = $matches[1];
$session_user[$session] += $username};
$logon_sessions |%{$starttime = [management.managementdatetimeconverter]::todatetime($_.starttime);
$loggedonuser = New-Object -TypeName psobject;
$loggedonuser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Session" -Value $_.logonid;
$loggedonuser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "User" -Value $session_user[$_.logonid];
$loggedonuser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Type" -Value $logontype[$_.logontype.tostring()];
$loggedonuser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Auth" -Value $_.authenticationpackage;
$loggedonuser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "StartTime" -Value $starttime;
$loggedonuser}
```

Help is appreciated.

Thanks, 
Sambhav

Comment: Hi, is PS running as administrator ?

Comment: Good point, i just discovered this point, and that was the issue indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you cannot get information about other user sessions if not running PowerShell **as administrator**.